# What would you call a criminal who is responsible for driving a car and helping the others escape?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

A simple question:

> What would you call a criminal who is responsible for driving a car and helping the others escape?

For instance, if a group of robbers rob a bank, there would be a person waiting in the car responsible for driving so that they can escape.  Is there a word for that person?

Comment: I've seen *wheelman* used occasionally, as in "[Andrew Paul Dion, accused of being the wheelman in an Oct. 10 robbery of a New Hartford bank...](http://www.registercitizen.com/article/RC/20100613/NEWS/306139974)"

Comment: @stangdon -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Informally:  The "getaway driver" was part of the gang of robbers.

Formally:  The "accomplice" "aided and [abetted](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/abet)" the bank robbery.

"Getaway driver" refers to the exact role you asked about.

"[Accomplice](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/accomplice)" is a more general term for someone who helps commit a crime.  The help might be before, during, or after the crime itself.

Comment: That's why I love this site! It gets you something *readymade* that you can't find anywhere! +1 for this! I always thought it's *partner in crime!*

Answer (score -1):

Partner in crime, aka, P.I.C; is, in my opinion, is the most essential person in a group of bandits. This person has to be the "eyes" & keep a look out for the authorities or any thing/one who could be the demise of their plans, plus he has to keep a level head and stay calm so that his roll can be achieved effectively and skillfully to complete the mission. Not to mention, the P.I.C is the one who has to deal with the aftermath of their deeds and has to be prepared for anything, because even though there was a plan, anything could happen. Ultimately, it's the P.I.C's duty to keep the gang out of jail..